# concatenate paths for linux and windows at the same time

Tags: python, path, concatenation

I have a script (python) supposed to build up two paths - one in Linux form(local) and another in Windows form (Windows share)

The script is running under Linux if it matters.

The os.path won't help for the Windows path. Does python have some helper for this case?

Any smart concatenation eliminating extra separators will help ...

Comment: well, os.path.join will use the os.path.sep, which in the case of Linux is '/', but '/' will also work under Windows (since XP I think)
edit: do you mean an SMB share with a FQNP or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can import and use the OS-specific path implementations:

```
import ntpath, posixpath

assert ntpath.join("a", "b") == r"a\b"
assert posixpath.join("a", "b") == "a/b"
```

When you import os.path, it examines the current OS to decide which of these modules to use, but you can simply use them directly if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which platform you are on, the `os` module will either use `import ntpath as path` (Windows) or `import posixpath as path` (*nix).  You can import these modules directly to do path manipulation as if you were on a different platform:

```
In [1]: import ntpath

In [2]: ntpath.join('dir', 'file')
Out[2]: 'dir\\file'

In [3]: import posixpath

In [4]: posixpath.join('dir', 'file')
Out[4]: 'dir/file'
```